# Creating a userscript that removes certain comments from YouTube

Tags: javascript, youtube, comments, userscripts

I find it very irritating when people comment on a YouTube video that they are watching the video in '2018' or whatever year it currently is, or ask others who are doing the same. Such comments usually get a lot of likes and thus stay near the top. So I started making a script that removes all such comments. I made the necessary code and successfully tested using the Chrome console.

Problem is, I don't know **how to keep it running/active**, so that whenever new comments are loaded or the page is refreshed, such comments get automatically filtered out. I used **window.setTimeout** but it only runs when the comments are already loaded. Doesn't work on newly loaded comments.

Any help is appreciated. Following is my script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTube Comment Cleaner
// @namespace    iamMG
// @include      *://www.youtube.com/*
// @description  Remove keywords from YouTube comments.
// @author       iamMG
// @license      MIT
// @version      1.0
// ==/UserScript==

//Some code to detect when the element with id 'watch-discussion' becomes available.
//It is the parent element which contains all the comments.
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var expr = /20(15|16|17|18|19|20)/; //The text I want to detect in comments
    var commentText = document.getElementsByClassName('comment-renderer-text-content'); //The text element within each comment
    for (var i =0; i<commentText.length; i++) {
        if (expr.test(commentText[i].innerText)) {      //tests for the substring inside the comment text.
            var elem = commentText[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;  //elem is the actual comment element.
            console.log('removed '+ (i+1) + 'th comment');
            elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            i--;
        }
    }
}, 4000)
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `setInterval` if you want it to apply to comments that load after page load. `setTimeout` says to execute ***in*** x ms, whereas `setInterval` says to execute ***every*** x ms.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to write it as an extension. You can use chrome.alarms to schedule the code. Also detect for DOM changes to figure if new comments are added if it gets added using websockets.